# Randomize dots on sphere and give them ID

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I try to create this [sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvAKe.png) in three.js. I need clickable dotes and meshes. So I think, that I can do this if I will give name for every dot in sphere.
Two questions:
1. How I can randomize positions of dots on sphere?
2. How I should to give names for dots and meshes?

```
THREE.IcosahedronGeometry = function(radius, detail) {
  var t = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;
  var vertices = [-1, t, 0, 1, t, 0, -1, -t, 0, 1, -t, 0,
    0, -1, t, 0, 1, t, 0, -1, -t, 0, 1, -t,
    t, 0, -1, t, 0, 1, -t, 0, -1, -t, 0, 1, -1, t, 0, 1, t, 0, -1, -t, 0, 1, -t, 0,
    0, -1, t, 0, 1, t, 0, -1, -t, 0, 1, -t,
    t, 0, -1, t, 0, 1, -t, 0, -1, -t, 0, 1
  ];
  var indices = [
    2,10,6,0, 11, 5, 0, 5, 1, 0, 1, 7, 0, 7, 10, 0, 10, 11,
    1, 5, 9, 5, 11, 4, 11, 10, 2, 10, 7, 6, 7, 1, 8,
    3, 9, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 3, 8, 9,
    4, 9, 5, 2, 4, 11, 6, 2, 10, 8, 6, 7, 9, 8, 1
  ];
  THREE.PolyhedronGeometry.call(this, vertices, indices, radius, detail);
  this.type = 'IcosahedronGeometry';
  this.parameters = {
    radius: radius,
    detail: detail
  };
};

THREE.IcosahedronGeometry.prototype = Object.create(THREE.PolyhedronGeometry.prototype);
THREE.IcosahedronGeometry.prototype.constructor = THREE.IcosahedronGeometry;

// Scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: 1
});

renderer.setClearColor(0xf7f7f7);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xd4d4d4, 8, 20);

// Create vertex points
var mesh = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(10, 2); // radius, detail
var vertices = mesh.vertices;

var positions = new Float32Array(vertices.length * 3);

for (var i = 0, l = vertices.length; i < l; i++) {
  vertices[i].toArray(positions, i * 3);
}
alert(positions);
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));

var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 0.4,
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
  color: 0x252525
});
var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);

var object = new THREE.Object3D();

object.add(points);

object.add(new THREE.Mesh(
  mesh,
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x616161,
    emissive: 0xa1a1a1,
    wireframe: true,
    fog: 1
  })

));

scene.add(object);

camera.position.z = 20;

var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  object.rotation.x += 0.001;
  object.rotation.y += 0.001;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLpPxB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example how you could randomize the points: http://codepen.io/usefulthink/pen/WRoboo?editors=0010

The interesting bit is this:

```
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3();
var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();

for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 3) {
    v3.fromArray(vertices, i);
    spherical.setFromVector3(v3);

    spherical.phi += rnd(variation, -variation);
    spherical.theta += rnd(variation, -variation);

    v3.setFromSpherical(spherical);
    v3.toArray(vertices, i);
}
```

In short, a good way to manipulate points on the surface of a sphere is to use [spherical-coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (phi/theta/r instead of x/y/z, think latitude/longitude). In this case I convert each of the vertices into the spherical form, manipulate the theta/phi-values a bit (keeping the radius as it is) and write the modified values back to the vertices-array.

I am not sure what you mean with giving names to these points. Something like this?

```
var pointNames = {
  frank: 12, 
  maria: 7, 
  steve: 3, 
  melissa: 4
};

function getPointByName(name) {
  const startIndex = pointNames[name] * 3;
  return new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(vertices, index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, Martin. Good idea with spherical coordinates!  About names - I wanna  give id for every dot, because I need to use every dot like a link with hover effects etc.

Comment: Oh, in that case you should probably do something like what I've shown, but create a new Mesh at every point. You can then just set the name on the mesh (`mesh.name = 'some-name';`) and use `scene.getObjectsByName('some-name')` to retrieve it.